# Подключение к веб-сокету из приложения (Android WebSocket)

Tags: android

Есть сервер, обслуживающий подключения к веб-сокетам из клиентских браузеров. Встала задача подключиться к нему из приложения Android (не из браузера телефона). Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взять исходник [WebSocket.java](https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap/blob/master/src/com/strumsoft/websocket/phonegap/WebSocket.java) и убрать все, что касается WebView. После этого работа с сокетом проста

```
WebSocket ws = new WebSocket(URI.create("ws://someserver.com"), DRAFT-76, "some_id");

ws.connect();
```

Или воспользоваться этим клиентом: [weberknecht - Java WebSocket Client Library](http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht/).

Answer (score 0):

Java WebSocket Client не поддерживает послединй стандарт websocket (RFC 6455), а остановился на поддержке "черновиков" протокола. Это может привести к неожиданным проблемам. Попробуйте использовать библиотеку [AutobahnAndroid](http://autobahn.ws/developers/autobahnandroid). О сравнении этих библиотек и о подключении к websocket из Andriod-приложения подробнее написано [в этой статье](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2012/05/websoket-android.html)